# How to rotate AxesLabel

Tags: plotting, labeling

i was wondering how it is possible to rotate the axesLabel of a Plot in Mathematica. Specifically i want to rotate the Label of the Y-Axis so that it shows up next to the axes to use up less space. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So what i found is usind the Labeled function.

For example

```
Labeled[Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 9}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], {"Y axis", "X Axis"}, {Left, Bottom}, RotateLabel -> True]
```

Comment: Actually you can use AxesLabel->Rotate[Label,90 Degree]

Comment: @Wjx that will rotate the label, but it will still be positioned at the end of each axis, won't it? As I understood it, OP wanted the rotated label to be placed *to the side of the axes* it corresponds to, much like frame labels are positioned.

Comment: oh, right, I've misunderstood his goal.

Answer (score 2):

I often use `FrameLabel` in preference to axis labels.  This might suit you better:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True,  FrameLabel -> {"x-axis", "y-axis"}]
```