# Change distance between vertical y-axis label and plot

Tags: plotting, labeling, style

I'm trying to do something that should be fairly straightforward: having a vertical y-axis label. My problem is, it creates a ridiculously large space between the label and the axis (exactly what I'm trying to avoid). Here's my code, inspired from answers to [previous](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/117848/how-to-rotate-axeslabel) [questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16802/is-there-an-option-to-change-the-space-distance-between-tick-labels-and-axes-lab/16807), and the result.

```
Labeled[Plot[
    {p, p/(Exp[1.1]*(1-p)+p),p*Exp[1.1]/(1+p*(Exp[1.1]-1))},
    {p,0,1},
    PlotStyle->{Black ,Blue,Blue},
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
    AspectRatio->1,
    ImageMargins -> 0
  ],
  {"Initial suspicion","Updated suspicion"},
  {Bottom, Left},
  RotateLabel->True
]
```

[image: plot with very large space between y-axis and label]

Things I tried: using a `Frame` (doesn't work and breaks the style of axes), add zero or negative `Spacings` (same result), using `Rotate["updated suspicion", 90 Degree]` instead of `RotateLabel->True` (same result). Now I'm out of ideas, even though it feels like this should be simple.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include minimal working example of your code and data in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't like the frame around everything, you can specify the sides. With `FrameLabel`, the labeling you want can be done easily:

```
Plot[{p, p/(Exp[1.1]*(1 - p) + p), 
  p*Exp[1.1]/(1 + p*(Exp[1.1] - 1))}, {p, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue, Blue}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, ImageMargins -> 0, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Initial suspicion", "Updated suspicion"}, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Your command didn't give me exactly this graphic (on Wolfram Programming Lab), the ticks were gone. Adding `FrameTicks -> All` solved it, and I also added `PlotRangePadding -> 0` to fix the fact that the plot no longer starts at the origin. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I typically do use `FrameLabel` for this.

```
Plot[{p, p/(Exp[1.1]*(1 - p) + p), p*Exp[1.1]/(1 + p*(Exp[1.1] - 1))},
  {p, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue, Blue}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, ImageMargins -> 0, 
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Initial suspicion", "Updated suspicion"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

I started by defining a region which is just a white rectangle.  If you like, you can get a bounding box by uncommenting the EdgeForm:

p100 = Graphics[{(*EdgeForm[Thick]*), White, Rectangle[]}, AspectRatio -> 0.70,
ImageSize -> 486]

Then, you just put stuff in it wherever you like:

Show [ p100, Inset[p1,{0.25,0.25}], Inset["X-Axis",0.50,0.20] ]

Here, p1 is some plot.  You can make multipart figures this way, or annotate figures.  When I made p1, I use the option  FrameLabel->{"","Y-Axis"}

You have to do a little work with the numbers to place things where you want, but it's not hard.  I work with the EdgeForm on while I'm making the figure, then I turn it off when I want to save the final product.